# How can I find courses on MapMyRun?

Tags: tracking, app

The [courses page](http://www.mapmyrun.com/maps/courses) says

> Once a course is created, it acts like a virtual race. You can compete against other users for a spot on the public course leaderboard.

There are even achievements for being the fastest to complete a course. But... there's no way to search for courses other users have entered, so how am I supposed to run them?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about how to use a website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the founders wrote in the comments on [this page](https://support.mapmyfitness.com/hc/en-us/articles/200717065-Courses-FAQ) (as of April 17, 2014):

> Re: finding Courses. We are planning to add this functionality. For now, the best way to do this is by navigating to the City page for the area you are searching (Home menu/My City). Once on the city page there is a tab on the map that can be changed from routes to Courses. There is also a list of popular courses at the bottom of the page.